# post request allowed although denied

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

I started ajax post request to a php file like this:

```
$.post("URL_TO_PHP_FIlE", {parameter: 1}, function(response) {
  console.log(response)
}
```

And I get a response, but this should not be possible, because my php file only allows GET instead of POST:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
```

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) header is used in the preflight response to give the client a hint at which methods are allowed. It does not automatically block any incoming requests of any other type - that's something that you have to implement on your side, e.g. by returning a `405 Method Not Allowed` status code.

```php
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET' ) {
  http_response_code(405); exit;
}
```